# Stop select field resizing when the dropdown is opened

Tags: javascript, tom-select

Using TOM-SELECT - https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select

is it possible to stop select input resizing / autosizing when dropdown is opened?

It's a very disruptive behaviour - visually the dropdown field auto-resizes to the chosen selection.

This is not necessary if only 1 option can be selected (select field)

I just want dropdown to stay fixed width = to maximum option length.